# How to Solve Boolean Matrix System?

Tags: logic, algorithms, boolean-algebra, constraints, satisfiability

I have a Boolean Matrix System (BMS) as described below
$$Ax=c$$
where $A$ is a $n\times n$ Boolean matrix (i.e., all entries are either 0 or 1), $c$ and $x$ are two $n$-dimensional Boolean column vector. The product of two Boolean matrices $A_{m\times k}$ and $B_{k\times n}$ is $C_{m\times n}$, defined by
$$c_{ij}=\bigvee_{h=1}^{k}(a_{ih}\wedge b_{hj})$$

Assume $A$ and $c$ are given, now how to solve $x$?.

I have do some works. One way to do this is to transform a BMS to CNF, and solve it by SAT Solver. However, the transformation is quite sophisticated, and I have no idea to tackle it. Would you like to give me some advice?

$$  \begin{array}{cl}
    &~ b=Ax \\
    &~ \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \left[
                       \begin{array}{c}
                         b_1 \\
                         b_2 \\
                         \vdots \\
                         b_n \\
                       \end{array}
                     \right] = \left[
                       \begin{array}{c}
                         \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{1k} \wedge x_k) \\
                         \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{2k} \wedge x_k) \\
                         \vdots \\
                         \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{nk} \wedge x_k) \\
                       \end{array}
                     \right] \\
    &~ \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \left[
                       \begin{array}{c}
                         \left(\neg b_1 \vee \left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{1k} \wedge x_k)\right)\right) \wedge \left(b_1 \vee \neg\left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{1k} \wedge x_k)\right)\right)  \\
                         \left(\neg b_2 \vee \left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{2k} \wedge x_k)\right)\right) \wedge \left(b_1 \vee \neg\left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{2k} \wedge x_k)\right)\right) \\
                         \vdots \\
                         \left(\neg b_n \vee \left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{nk} \wedge x_k)\right)\right) \wedge \left(b_n \vee \neg\left( \bigvee^n_{k=1} (a_{nk} \wedge x_k)\right)\right) \\
                       \end{array}
                     \right]
  \end{array}$$

Comment: Consider your matrix to be over the boolean field $F_2 = \{0, 1\}$. Then the product described is just the regular product of matrices. Solving the system is exactly the same as solving it for a matrix over the real numbers, except that all additions are per the rules of $F_2$ (i.e., $1 + 1 = 0$). So just apply Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this approach, but this approach can find one solution. However, I want to find all solutions since there may be many solutions for this system.

Comment: No. $F_2$ is a field. If you do this right and find only one solution, then there is only one solution. If the system is singular, you may find more than one solution (or no solutions), just as in the case of a real matrix. But even then, Gaussian elimination will give you equations that you can use to find all values in terms of a set of independent ones. Unlike in the real case, since $F_2$ is finite, the total count of solutions is given by $2^k$, where $k$ is the number of independent variables.

Comment: Do you have any idea to solve this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528651/how-to-solve-this-boolean-equations