# How to Solve this Boolean Equations?

Tags: logic, algorithms, boolean-algebra, constraints, satisfiability

I have a Boolean Equations, described as below,
$$\neg \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{M}\cdot \neg(\mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{x})$$
in which $\mathbf{M}$ is an $n\times n$ Boolean matrix, and $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n\times 1$ Boolean column vector. The product of two Boolean matrices $A_{m\times k}$ and $B_{k\times n}$ is $C_{m\times n}$, defined by
$$c_{ij}=\bigvee_{h=1}^{k}(a_{ih}\wedge b_{hj})$$

Now, given $\mathbf{M}$, the task is to find all solutions of the equations.

Would you like to give me some idea?

Comment: I try to simplify the equations by introduce $\neg \mathbf{x} = 1 - \mathbf{x}$. Then, the equation can be rewrite as $1- \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{M}\cdot(1-\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{x})$. But the distributive law of multiplication can not be used on the right of this new equations. If this equations can be simplified, ....

Comment: Why can't the distributive law be used? As I indicated in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519311/how-to-solve-boolean-matrix-system?noredirect=1#comment3243386_1519311, these can be considered vectors and matrices over the field $\Bbb F_2$. And the distributive law holds there. I get that $$x = (M^2 - I)^{-1}(M - I)\mathbf 1$$ where $I$ is the identity matrx. I don't have time to work on it any further right now.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comment, if one considers the boolean values to be the field of two elements $\Bbb F_2$, then your boolean matrices are just regular matrices over that field. $\vee$ becomes addition modulo $2$, and $\wedge$ becomes multiplication modulo $2$. Your definition of boolean matrix multiplication is just ordinary multiplication between matrices. Thus your matrices are linear operators on $\Bbb F_2^n$, which means that $$M(a\mathbf x + b\mathbf y) = aM\mathbf x + bM\mathbf y.$$
So your equation becomes
$$\mathbf 1 - \mathbf x = M(\mathbf 1 - M\mathbf x) = M\mathbf 1 - M^2\mathbf x$$
$$M^2\mathbf x - \mathbf x = M\mathbf 1 - \mathbf 1$$
$$(M^2 - I)\mathbf x = (M - I)\mathbf 1$$
$$(M - I)(M + I)\mathbf x = (M - I)\mathbf 1$$
If $M - I$ is invertible, then 
$$(M + I)\mathbf x =\mathbf 1$$
If $M + I$ is also invertible, then
$$\mathbf x = (M + I)^{-1}\mathbf 1$$

Comment: What is your definition about the operator "-" on Boolean variable, 1-1=?, 1-0=?, 0-1 = ? and 0-0=?

Comment: Does XOR instead of OR ($\vee$) corresponds to addition modulo 2? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate

Comment: @Paul how does $\lor$ become addition mod 2? The question defines multiplication using OR, not XOR.